# joint probability function of 2 independent Bernoilli trials

Tags: probability

I'm stuck on the last part of this problem:

> Repeated independent Bernoulli trials are performed, each with probability p of success. Let $X_1$ be the trial number of the first success and let $X_2$ bet the trial number of the second success. What is the joint probability function for $(X_1,X_2)$? Derive the marginal probability laws for $X_1$ and $X_2$

The first two-thirds of this problem is pretty easy, see my solutions below:

First, consider trial 1 (represented by the random variable $X_1$). It is obvious that this is a geometric random variable with the probability law:

$p_{X_1}(k) = p\ q^{k-1}$

$X_2$ is also a geometric random variable, but with the added constraint that its even must occur after event $X_1$, therefore the range of $X_2$ is $R_{X_2} = \{x_1+1,x_1 +2,...\}. $ With this information we can formulate the joint probability function:

$f_{X_1,X_2} = pq^{x_1-1}*pq^{x_2-x_1-1} = p^2q^{x_2-2}$

now, working backwards to find the marginal probability of $X_1$:

$p_{X_1}(x_1) = \displaystyle\sum_{x_2 = x_1+1}^{n}{p^2q^{x_2-2}} = pq^{x_1-1}$

which makes sense since this is a geometric random variable.

Now the marginal probability for $X_2$ should obviously be the Negative binomial probability law for for 2 successes, and thus $p_{X_2}(x_2) = \binom{x_2-1}{1}p^2q^{x_2-2}$

however, when you sum over the joint probability law, you get:

$p_{X_2}(x_2) = \displaystyle\sum_{x_1=1}^{x_2-1}p^2q^{x_2-2} = p^2q^{x_2-2}(1+2+3+...+x_2-1) = \binom{x_2}{2}p^2q^{x_2-2}$

Any idea where I'm going wrong here? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is correct, except at the very end.

The correct calculation is:  $$\Pr[X_2 = x_2] = \sum_{x_1 = 1}^{x_2 - 1} p^2 (1-p)^{x_2-2} = (x_2 - 1)p^2(1-p)^{x_2-2}.$$  This is simply because the summand $p^2(1-p)^{x_2-2}$ is **constant** with respect to the index of summation $x_1$.  I'm not sure how you got $(1+2+\cdots+(x_2-1))$, because there's no $x_1$ term in the summand.

Comment: oh, that was a dumb oversight. Thanks for the help!